# Support css3 rotate and scale on IE8 and earlier

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, css, transform

I want to make rotate and scale on IE8, I used this [library](http://www.zachstronaut.com/posts/2009/08/07/jquery-animate-css-rotate-scale.html) but it breaks on IE8 and return an Error

```
 'undefined' is null or not an object and pints to line 62 of this script.
```

Is there is any solution to make scale and rotate in jquery rather than using transform?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is http://code.google.com/p/jqueryrotate/.  You can see examples at http://code.google.com/p/jqueryrotate/wiki/Examples. JqueryRotate works in IE6+.